# How to detect exceptions in delegated tasks (SSLEngine)

Tags: java, exception, jsse, sslengine

I use `SSLEngine`s together with NIO to provide nonblocking SSL connections to my application. At some point during the handshake (probably after receiving `ServerHelloDone`) the `SSLEngine` requires me to process a delegated task.

So I call `getDelegatedTask` and call it's `run` method. The task itself calls `X509ExtendedKeyManager.getCertificateChain`, which in turn throws an `NullPointerException`. That exception is caught by the `Handshaker` and stored for later reporting.

However reporting works by calling the private `checkTaskThrown` method that is only called when a message was received or a message is to be sent.
But without `getCertificateChain` to complete correctly, there is nothing to send and the other side sends nothing as well, so there is nothing to receive. Hence the exception stays hidden.

As no side proceeds, we have a livelock.
And I found no way to prevent or detect that, except for

- Using reflection to call `checkTaskThrown`
- Use some task / timer for a timeout

Neither of which is the route I want to go...

Comment: When the task completes you should retry the operation that returned NEED_TASK. But why does it throw a NullPointerException?

Comment: You were actually right. My code did actually call `getHandshakeStatus` and got `NEED_UNWRAP` but as there was nothing in the `sourceByteBuffer` an internal optimization bit me and `unwrap` was not called. Please repost your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the task completes you should retry the operation that returned `NEED_TASK.`

You need to find and fix the NPE in your `KeyManager.`